# How to preserve row headers after PCA from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have an array like so:

```
sampleA 1 2 2 1 
sampleB 1 3 2 1
sampleC 2 3 1 2
```

My goal is to run PCA across the samples and see their clustering. However, I need to preserve the sample names in the row header. Is there any way I can do this? Desired PCA result includes the row headers:

```
sampleA 0.13 0.1
sampleB 0.1 0.4
sampleC 0.1 0.1
```

Currently just running these two simple lines:

```
my_pca = PCA(n_components=8)
trans = my_pca.fit_transform(in_array)
```

Comment: Just wondering how you make the code work? The shape of your array is `(3, 4)`. If you fit that with `n_components=8`, you should get a error message. If I fit that with `n_components=2`, I didn't get the result, `sampleA 0.13 0.1`, you've mentioned. Am I missing something here?

Comment: sorry, my actual data is a much larger array which definitely would not fit into a comment box easily :)

Comment: No problem. It's just that I cannot reproduce your results with your code and I'm afraid of being stupid by missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L310), you input will be transformed by `np.array()` before doing PCA. So you will lose the row index during `PCA.fit_transform(X)` even you use a structured array or a pandas DataFrame. However, the order of your data is preserved, meaning you can attach the index back if you want:

```
import io

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

s = """sampleA 1 2 2 1
sampleB 1 3 2 1
sampleC 2 3 1 2"""
in_array = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0)
my_pca = PCA(n_components=2)
trans = my_pca.fit_transform(in_array)
df = pd.DataFrame(trans, index=in_array.index)
print(df)
#                 0         1
# 0                          
# sampleA -0.773866 -0.422976
# sampleB -0.424531  0.514022
# sampleC  1.198397 -0.091046
```

Comment: thanks, the order preservation knowledge was very helpful

Comment: @Y. Luo Does that mean that no records are deleted when PCA is applied?